# AngularJS Issue With time Input Formatting

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and am having an issue with formatting the time object to populate my "time" input field in Android and Firefox.  I have spent hours trying to figure out the issue and also utilized AngularJS's documentation to try and figure this out, but have had no luck.

I am dynamically populating an input field from JSON, and the result is always in the following format:  14:57:00.000

I need it to look like this in the input field:  2:57 PM

Here is the link to AngularJS that I have been referring to:  [AngularJS time input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D#!).  At the bottom of the page is the plunker to run.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide me.

Comment: We need to see how you're implementing that code. Since you're getting the data from JSON, it's likely the value is a string, not a Date object as shown in that link.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/BEi1sgzwBHNj1iEjrZBb?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
{{myTime | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently on the road and cannot get to a computer to get my code posted. Could you show me how to apply that to an input? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use the plunker example on the angularjs website I provided in my initial comment? Thanks again.

Comment: <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "shortTime"}}</tt><br/>